# How to require module extension code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I need to extend Active Merchant module to include my own code, I'm following the article here
http://blog.matthodan.com/how-to-add-support-for-paypal-website-payment

As per the article, I created paypal_recurring_payments.rb in /vendor/plugins/active_merchant/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/. Next I have to modify an Active Merchant gem file paypal.rb to add a line of code. The problem is that I can't deploy that code change to Heroku, so I need an alternate way of doing this. Any insights will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fork the gem on [github](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)
2. Make the appropriate change to your fork of the gem.
3. Reference your fork in the Gemfile using the :git option. See the [docs](http://gembundler.com/git.html) for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I really like to avoid creating a new gem just for that, isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Depending on your changes you can monkey match your changes in a Rails initializer. However, since the line your adding seems to be just a require. You can probably get by by adding the require to an initializer instead.

Comment: That'll be preferred, how do I do that exactly?

Comment: Personally, I like to place all of my gem extensions in a separate directory but for the easiest method to get what i think you want done is to place the file you had in 'vendor/plugins' in config/initializers/paypal_recurring_payments.rb. This will automatically get loaded by rails on startup.

Comment: I'm with you on putting the vendor file in the vendor directory, is there an easy way to accomplish that? BTW, putting the file where you said worked. I am thinking there should be a way to require the file from a model.rb file but can't figure out the syntax

Comment: I use an 'extensions' directory. You can get rails to load it by updating adding this line to your application.rb `config.autoload_paths += "#{config.root}/extensions"`

Comment: @diedthreetimes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1484/discussion-between-bob-and-diedthreetimes)